# Add property or function to method of a Class

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, methods

I am just learning Typescript and I wanted to realize this logic in **ts**.
So far I have not found correct information.

**Javascript**

```js
class A{
 constructor(){
  this.user.name = () => 'Eduardo'
  this.user.lastname = () => 'Alva'
 }

 user(){
  return {
   name: 'Eduardo',
   lastname: 'Alva'
  }
 }
}

const a = new A()

a.user() // { name: 'Eduardo', lastname: 'Alva' }
a.user.name() // 'Eduardo'
a.user.lastname() // 'Alva'
```

**Typescript**

```
class A{
 constructor(){
  this.user.name = () => 'Eduardo' // Property 'name' does not exist on type '() => void'
  this.user.lastname = () => 'Alva' // Property 'lastname' does not exist on type '() => void'
 }

 public user(){
  return {
   name: 'Eduardo',
   lastname: 'Alva'
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This looks like a bad idea even in JS. Don't put arbitrary properties on prototype methods, at least not from inside of the constructor of your class.

Comment: This is code example. How do you recommend me in Typescript?

Comment: As I said, I recommend to not do this at all. You might want to show us your actual code if you think the example doesn't convey the purpose properly - or just explain why you think you need to do this.

Comment: It's a bit complicated to explain because of my english, but I share my code.
https://github.com/Aventura-Tech/redity/blob/master/src/state.js

Comment: I want to pass it to a Class in Typescript.

Comment: You mean `this.change`? That's an instance method, not a prototype method, which would at least work properly. (You cannot make it a `class` method). I would still recommend to avoid nested/"namespaced" functions, instead just make it a `changeValue` method (etc.). That way you can actually profit from prototypical inheritance.

Comment: To type `this.change` in TypeScript, you'd probably need to declare it as a [callable object type](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/callable.html)